# Import module in MRJob on EMR

Tags: python, hadoop, emr, mrjob

Simple question: I have a module headers.py which defines a couple variables I need in my main MRJob script. I should be able to run the job with

```
python MRMyJob -r emr --file=headers.py s3://input/data/path
```

and then in my MRJob script (MRMyJob), the following should work:

```
from headers import header1, header2, header3
```

Right? From the mrjob --help page: "--file=UPLOAD_FILES
                        Copy file to the working directory of this script. You
                        can use --file multiple times."

I'm still getting "no module named headers" when I try to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`headers.py` is apparently not put in your remote `PYTHONPATH`. See [the docs](http://packages.python.org/mrjob/writing-and-running.html#putting-your-source-tree-in-the-pythonpath) on how to get additional modules across to the cluster; you have to put them in a tarball first.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks. Still not sure why --file doesn't work, though. Shouldn't python be able to import from the cwd, even if it's not on PYTHONPATH?